# How to acquire the Context in an Adobe AIR Native Extension?

Tags: java, android, air-native-extension

In the following line of code...

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getBaseContext(), "LOADING_TITLE", "LOADING_MESSAGE");
```

In place of getBaseContext() I've tried...

```
getApplicationContext() // returns "java.lang.NullPointerException"
getBaseContext() // returns "java.lang.NullPointerException"
(NativeActivity)getApplicationContext()
this // returns "The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence) in the Type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments(new Runnable(){}, String, String)"
NativeActivity.this // returns "java.lang.NullPointerException"
NativeActivity.this.getApplicationContext() // returns "java.lang.NullPointerException"
NativeExtension.context.getActivity().getBaseContext() // returns “android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is not for an application”
myActivity.getApplicationContext() // returns “android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is not for an application”
myActivity.getBaseContext() // returns “android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is not for an application”
```

Among others. I'm not sure why it's not working. In the NativeExtensionContext which extends FREContext I am passing the activity using getActivity() to NativeActivity. Everything works well but I get a "Nullpointerexception" or “android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” when I try I try to get a reference to the Context.

Anyone with experience using Adobe AIR Native Extensions and/or Android Java would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
NativeExtension.context.getActivity().getBaseContext() // this should work.
```

The only thing I can think of is make sure that you are working from inside an Activity.  That is, an Activity that you initialize from your FREFunction instance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your classs:

```
public static FREContext myANEContext=null;

....
....

  ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(myANEContext.getActivity().getBaseContext(), "LOADING_TITLE", "LOADING_MESSAGE");
```

dont forget to pass the value from the `FREFunction` before using your class:

```
  public class MyANEfunction implements FREFunction{


    @Override
      public FREObject call(final FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {
      try{
            myANEClass.myANEContext=context;

         ....
```